# Search form pdf attachment using elasticsearch-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

How to index pdf attachment into elasticsearch server using elasticsearch-rails

My code is bellow

```
module Searchable
extend ActiveSupport::Concern

included do
include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

__elasticsearch__.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
__elasticsearch__.client.transport.logger.formatter = proc { |s, d, p, m| "\e[32m#{m}\n\e[0m" }

include Indexing
after_touch() { __elasticsearch__.index_document }
end

module Indexing

# Customize the JSON serialization for Elasticsearch
  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    self.as_json(
      include: {
               comments: { only: :message }
             })
           {
             name: "#{title} - #{id}",
             comments: comments,

             attachment: Base64.encode64(File.open(Rails.root.to_s + '/public' + resume.to_s) { |io| io.read }).to_json
           }
   end

 end

end
```

This code only indexing content of file as base64_encode format. Please help me.